# How to target a record of table B to and Id of Table A based on a time restriction?

Tags: sql, sql-server

**Objective:** I would like to match a transaction_id to the first note that was inputted in the system within 20 minutes of the transcation_id's timestamp.

**Situation:** Both tables are linked by email. Email aa@email.com for example as a transaction_id recorded at 3:59 am on jan 1st 2019. I would like to see if a note was inserted within 20 mns. So Note 1 of table 2 should be targeted. Basically the first occurence. For the second transaction (associated to email zz@email.com), no note would be attached to it since the first note insert is > 20mns.

Table 1:

```
+---------------------+---------------+------------------+
| timestamp           |    email      |   transaction_id |
+---------------------+---------------+---------------- -+
| 2019-01-01 03:59:00 | aa@email.com  |    123           |
| 2018-12-31 09:00:00 | zz@email.com  |    456           |
+---------------------+-------------+--------------------+
```

Table 2:

```
+--------------+--------+---------------------+
|    email     |  note  |      timestamp      |
+--------------+--------+---------------------+
| aa@email.com | note 1 | 2019-01-01 04:00:00 |
| aa@email.com | note 2 | 2019-01-01 04:15:00 |
| aa@email.com | note 3 | 2019-01-01 04:20:00 |
| aa@email.com | note 4 | 2019-01-01 04:25:00 |
| aa@email.com | note 5 | 2019-01-01 06:15:00 |
| zz@email.com | note 1 | 2019-01-01 08:15:00 |
| zz@email.com | note 2 | 2019-01-01 08:16:00 |
|              |        |                     |
+--------------+--------+---------------------+
```

**Output:**

```
+---------------------+--------------+----------------+-------+---------------------+--+
|      timestamp      |    email     | transaction_id | note  |   note_timestamp    |  |
+---------------------+--------------+----------------+-------+---------------------+--+
| 2019-01-01 03:59:00 | aa@email.com |            123 | note1 | 2019-01-01 04:00:00 |  |
+---------------------+--------------+----------------+-------+---------------------+--+
```

**What i tried:**

```
SELECT t1.timestamp
    ,t1.email
    ,t1.transaction_id
    ,Emails
    ,Dates
FROM t1
    INNER JOIN 
        (
        SELECT t2.email AS Emails
            ,t2.note AS Notes
            ,t2.timestamp AS Dates
            ,ROW_NUMBER()
                OVER(PARTITION BY t2.email ORDER BY t2.timestamp ASC) AS Top1_note
        FROM t2
        ) AS Subquery 
    ON t1.email=Subquery.Emails
```

Im not sure what to put as a `WHERE` or `HAVING` condition to restrict the dates of the note to 20mns after the transcation date

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `CROSS APPLY` to get all the notes within 20 minutes. Use `row_number()` to get only (one of) the oldest note(s).

```
SELECT *
       FROM table1 t1
            CROSS APPLY (SELECT *,
                                row_number() OVER (ORDER BY timestamp) rn
                                FROM table2 t2
                                     WHERE t2.email = t1.email
                                           AND t2.timestamp >= t1.timestamp
                                           AND t2.timestamp <= dateadd(minute, 20, t1.timestamp)) x
       WHERE x.rn = 1;
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2012&fiddle=888e9802b74bf82014cfa60a03071909)

Comment: the WHERE t2.email = t1.email replaces the PARTITION BY email clause in the row_number?

Comment: @RogerSteinberg: Partitioning by email would be pointless as the email is the same across all rows here.

Comment: so whats the difference between inner join and cross apply here. i know this question is not relevant to the question, but not sure i get it

Comment: @RogerSteinberg: With `APPLY` you can use the values from the outer query in the subquery. Here limit the records to those in the 20 minutes. With joins you cannot do that.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an alternative approach that does it use window functions.

The query first selects all notes related to the transaction (within the next 20 minutes), and then uses a NOT EXISTS condition with a correlated subquery to keep only the most recent one.

```
SELECT
    t1.*, t2.note, t2.timestamp note_timestamp
FROM 
    table1 t1
    INNER JOIN table2 t2 
        ON t1.email = t2.email
        AND t2.timestamp >=  t1.timestamp 
        AND t2.timestamp < DATEADD(MINUTE, 20, t1.timestamp)
WHERE 
    NOT EXISTS (
        SELECT 1
        FROM table2
        WHERE 
            email = t2.email
            AND timestamp > t2.timestamp
            AND timestamp < DATEADD(MINUTE, 20, t1.timestamp)
    )
```

Comment: what does select 1 do here? and why not exists instead of exists?

Comment: @RogerSteinberg : the purpose of this NOT EXISTS condition is to ensure that the row that we are selecting is the latest one (so it says : ensure that NO more recent record EXISTS). As this condition is only there to check if a row EXISTS (the content of that row is not actually useful), we use « SELECT 1 »

Answer (score 1):

Try this ,

```
 SELECT  TOP 1 t1.[timestamp] ,t1.[Email],t1.transaction_id 
      ,t2.[Note]
      ,t2.[timestamp] as  note_timestamp
       FROM table1 t1 inner Join table2 t2
       on t2.email = t1.email
       And   t2.timestamp >= t1.timestamp
       AND t2.timestamp <= dateadd(minute, 20, t1.timestamp)
```